# Ng-repeat alert

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<tr ng-repeat="sce in users">
  <td>
    <a href="/test/delete?id={{sce.id}}" 
        onclick="return confirm('You really want to delete'+ {{sce.name}} + 'from list');" >
           <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </a>
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Pero se va directo a borrar, no me sale el alert.

El error que cojo en consola es:

```
Error: [$compile:nodomevents] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$compile/nodomevents
```

Comment: Quizas esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313576/confirmation-dialog-on-ng-click-angularjs/18313962#18313962) te ayude, es un caso muy similar.

Answer (score 0):

en los elementos `<a></a>` para que `onclick` se ejecute, debe terminar con una expresion que devuelva true, o sea en tu caso `return true`;

Por ejemplo

```html
<tr ng-repeat="sce in users">
  <td>
    <a href="/test/delete?id={{sce.id}}" 
        onclick="return confirm('You really want to delete'+ {{sce.name}} + 'from list'); return true;" >
           <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </a>
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Debiera funcionar. Pero de todos modos, iria luego a `/test/delete?id=xx`.

Si quieres que no vaya a la page `/test/delete?id=xx`, debes retornar `false`. Es el comportamiento por defecto del onclick en elementos `<a>`.

Como ves, es enliado, la razon es que no debieras usar onclick en elementos `<a>`, para esto tienes los botones u otros.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, si te fijas tengo en el onclick return, segun conteste ok o cancel, el problema me lo esta dando {{sce.name}} que tengo un error en consola

Comment: ah cierto, confirm retorna boolean. tu coleccion de usuarios no tiene elementos nulos?

Comment: el problem que lo que intento hacer no se puede parece: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nodomevents

Comment: Tiene sentido, angular no podria saber si es codigo javascript o una interpolacion. ng-click no te sirve?quitar el href quiza y hacer la redireccion con window.location.href = '/item/delete?id=xx' luego de hacer el confirm? No se si es lo mejor, pero es lo que suelo hacer yo

Answer (score 0):

Como normalmente es mejor separar el HTML y el Javascript por la filosofia de [separación de intereses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separaci%C3%B3n_de_intereses), te recomiendo capturar el evento mediante un script.

**Primera opción:** Capturar evento "Click"

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
var confirmIt = function (e) {
    var nombre = e.target.dataset.nombre;
    if (!confirm('You really want to delete '+ nombre + ' from list')) e.preventDefault();
};
for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
}
```

```html
<a href="/test/delete?id={{sce.id}}" class="confirmation" data-nombre="{{sce.name}}">Link</a>
```

**Segunda opción:** Llamar a una función pasando parametros

```js
function deleteIt(id, nombre) {
  var deleteUrl = window.location.hostname + "/test/delete?id=" + id;
  var texto = "You really want to delete " + nombre + " from list";
  if (confirm(texto)) {
    window.location.href = deleteUrl;
  }
};
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="deleteIt(1, 'Nombre')">Borrar Ejemplo estatico</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="deleteIt({{sce.id}}, {{sce.name}})">Borrar Dinamico</a> <-- Solo funcionara tras renderizar las variables.
```

**EDITADO:** Se ha agregado una segunda opción.

Comment: en tu ejemplo funciona pero no en mi casa, podrias hacerlo q llame a una funcion mejor? de la forma que lo haces recorre buscando todos los lementos que tengas confirmation y mejor seria si llamo al metodo en concreto

Comment: Los elementos que tengan confirmation es como si les agregaras la función, cada vez que se toca un elemento, la función solo afecta al elemento que la llamo.

Comment: Si pero por algun motivo me esta redirigiendo directamente :s